# finding process id using program name

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, pid

My program receives a string (a shell script's path) as input. Now I have to launch that shell script and find out the process id for it.

I'm using the `system()` function to launch a shell script and after that using `popen()` with `ps -aef | grep "ShellScript"` to get its PID.

It's being suggested to me that there's a better way to do it. The way I did it will give a wrong PID if multiple scripts are running at same time.

What is the correct way to get a PID for a given script name after launching it?

Comment: _"It will give wrong PID if multiple script is running at same time."_ So you have to handle multiple PIDs?

Comment: Maybe look up [fork()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and [exec()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)?

Comment: Maybe it's the easiest way to replace `system()` by `fork()` and `exec...()`. But: how do you achieve things at the moment? Normally `system()` would not return until the Script has finished ...

Comment: Why do you need to get the PID?  What will you do with it?

Comment: wrong PID it gives for multiple scripts running.

Comment: I used " &" in system() to make it run in background

Comment: As per requirement, I need to return this PID.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should not use `system()`.

A better approach would be using `fork()`, which returns a `PID` > 0 if you are in the parent process and `return` 0 if you are in the child. 
Any other return satus is an error and `errno` is set accordingly.

When you are in the child process you should `exec` your command, while you should either `wait` for it in the parent one if you want to avoid to have a zombie process or handle `SIGCHLD`  signal.

Always read `man` for better insight.

Here is a brief example

```
int pid = -1;

If((pid = fork()) > 0)
{
     /* Parent process*/
     wait(NULL);
}
else if(pid == 0)
{
    /*Child process*/
    execv(....);

    exit (0);
}
else
{
    /*Error*/
    perror("fork()");
}
```